# How do I upload a Google Doc file to Google drive in native Google format?

Tags: google-docs-api

I download a Google Doc file in Json format (application/vnd.google-apps.document) from Google using [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get).

How do I upload this file back to Google Drive? The description for [documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) method clearly says that it can create only a blank document:

> Creates a **blank document** using the title given in the request. Other
>   fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored.

Are there any other method to upload application/vnd.google-apps.document (in native Google format, not docx)?

Note that unlike [documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create),  [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) method allows uploading file content and works just fine.

Comment: I think that this might be a bug. This has already been reported to the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123897235 Docs API is growing now. So for example, about the batchUpdate method, Docs API has not the request for updating the tableCellStyle yet. By this situation, I think that the completely copy of Document using JSON object cannot be achieved now.

Comment: As other workarounds, for example, it seems that the get method of Docs API can retrieve the complete JSON of Document. Using this, it creates a Document with Google Apps Script. In this case, the complex script is required to be prepared. As another one, although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, it directly modifies Google Document using Docs API and/or Google Apps Script. In the case that only the part you want to modify is modified, the script might be simple. If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.